# Read Data from Firebase and put it in Cells in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So basically I want to get the amount of holes from the uialert and then put them in my database and then receive them in my other view controller to fill it with for example 18 cells which each have the title from 1 - 18, but I don't know how to get for example 18 cells and the cell 1 to have the title 1 and cell 2 to have title 2 and so on.

here's my database:

[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObcrO.png)

Here's where i want to add all the holes to tableview:

```
class HolesViewController: UITableViewController {

    //TODO ADD CELLS FROM FIREBASE INSIDE COURSES.CHILD 
    //G/L FROM INPUT DATA IN NEXT VIEWCONTROLLER 

    //FirebaseRefrences
    var ref = FIRDatabaseReference.init()

    var holes: [FIRDataSnapshot]! = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        //ViewDidLoad



        //Refrences to Firebase

        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        let CoursesRef = ref.child("Courses")
        var holes: [FIRDataSnapshot]! = []


        print()



        //snapshot

        CoursesRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshpt in

            //self.courses.append(snapshpt)
            //self.tableView.reloadData()
            //print(snapshpt.childSnapshotForPath("Holes"))

            self.holes.append(snapshpt.childSnapshotForPath("Holes"))
            print(self.holes)

            //self.tableView.reloadData()
        })


    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        //ViewDidAppear
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.holes.count

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell: UITableViewCell! = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HoleCell")

        let holesSnap = self.holes[indexPath.row]

        let holes = holesSnap.value

        /*

         ??????

        */

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {

        return true
    }


}
```

Here's where i get the data for the holes from:

```
@IBAction func addButtonDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {


        // Alert View for input

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Course Item",message: "Add Course",preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .Default) { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in

            //Get Date String
            let date = NSDate()
            print(date)

            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy 'at' HH:mm"
            let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
            print(dateString)
            //
            let courseField = alert.textFields![0]
            let holesField = alert.textFields![1]



            let Courses = self.ref.child("Courses").childByAutoId()

            let course = ["AddedDate": dateString as AnyObject,
                          "CourseName": courseField.text as! AnyObject,
                          "AmountOfHoles": holesField.text as! AnyObject]

            Courses.setValue(course)

            //SET HOLES INSIDE COURSES

            let holes = Courses.child("Holes")
            //let holesChild = holes.child("")
            let eightteenholes = ["1": "1",
                                 "2": "2",
                                 "3": "3",
                                 "4": "4",
                                 "5": "5",
                                 "6": "6",
                                 "7": "7",
                                 "8": "8",
                                "9": "9",
                                "10": "10",
                                "11": "11",
                                "12": "12",
                                "13": "13",
                                "14": "14",
                                "15": "15",
                                "16": "16",
                                "17": "17",
                                "18": "18"]

            let nineholes = ["1": "1",
                                 "2": "2",
                                 "3": "3",
                                 "4": "4",
                                 "5": "5",
                                 "6": "6",
                                 "7": "7",
                                 "8": "8",
                                 "9": "9"]

            let sixholes = ["1": "1",
                            "2": "2",
                            "3": "3",
                            "4": "4",
                            "5": "5",
                            "6": "6"]

            if holesField.text == "18"{

                holes.setValue(eightteenholes)

            } else if self.AmonuOfHoles == "9"{

                holes.setValue(nineholes)

            } else if self.AmonuOfHoles == "6"{

                holes.setValue(sixholes)

            }



        }
```

Comment: try `CoursesRef.queryOrderedByChild("CourseName")
        .queryEqualToValue("eps").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshpt in`

Comment: I don't quite get it..where would i put that?

Comment: in viewdidload ... replace your query with this

Comment: ok but how do i get the cells to display in tableview with the correct title

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving data from Firebase to tableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39775232/retrieving-data-from-firebase-to-tableview)