# Retrieving data from Firebase to tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In a view, my user types some text in a input field, which I save as a `ticket` (*this process works without problems and are added to my database successfully*).

I want all these `ticket` values to be presented in a `tableView` in which each cell contains a `ticket`. I've been playing around, and this is as far as I could go, but it is still not enough.

```
 import UIKit
 import Firebase

 class TestTableViewController: UITableViewController {

let cellNavn = "cellNavn"

  var holes: [FIRDataSnapshot]! = []


let CoursesRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Ticketcontainer")


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    CoursesRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
        self.holes = snapshot.childSnapshotForPath("tickets").children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot]
    })

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleCancel))

    tableView.registerClass(UserCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellNavn)


}


func handleCancel() {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellNavn, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UserCell                       
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.holes[indexPath.row].value as? String

    return cell

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 72
}    

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all in `numberOfRowsInSection` method you need to return your array's count instead of some static value.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return holes.count
}
```

Second after initializng your array in closure you need to reload the `tableView`.

```
CoursesRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
    self.holes = snapshot.childSnapshotForPath("tickets").children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot]
    self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

Comment: I got it to work with your help but I also for some reason had to change .ChildAdded to .Value. 

I now get the whole table, however I would still think with .Childadded it would show the last "ticket" that had been applied to the list of tickets?

Comment: @Frederic Don't understand what you said please explain in detail what issue you are facing.

Comment: I'm sorry! At first when I implemented your code I just got a blank white table view, I then changed ".ChildAdded" in my observeEventType to ".Value"

And then it did work. It now shows all the values from my database. 

Now I was just wondering if it would be possible to only show the ticket that "just was typed in by the user", (thats is why I tried with .Childadded, but it is just blank. 

Hope I made myself more clear and I appreciate your help!